# How to use vcvarsall.bat in Python for NMake

Tags: python, batch-file

I'm trying to make a python script to make some generation of MakeFile with CMake. I'm newbie in Python and just know the basic.

My script runs well but I can't use following command `"cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G"NMake Makefiles" ..\\..\\graphics"` because it says :

> cmake must be run from a shell that can use the compiler cl from the
>   command line.

I know the issue and normally I use call (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`) and that's working. How I can reproduce that in Python ?

Here is my script.py :

```
from os import *
from subprocess import *

path = "C:\\Users\\mea\\Documents\\repos\\corealpi\\cmake\\graphics_nmake"
chdir(path)
info = getcwd()
print(info)
call("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat")
system('cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G"NMake Makefiles" ..\\..\\graphics')
system("pause")
path = "C:\\Users\\mea\\Documents\\repos\\corealpi\\cmake\\graphics_nmake"
chdir(path)
print (getcwd())
system('ls')
```

I have had some command path to verify I'm under the good directory.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options;

- You can change your system path to include the path exposed by `vcvars.bat`
- You can edit your shell's path initialization and add the paths you need

I usually do the first one so that I can also use the commands from a regular windows CMD shell.

Comment: @AI G I've add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin` to my path system variable but it seems that doesn't work in Python and windows CMD...

Comment: Did you restart the cmd window after changing your env? Otherwise if it's not working from CMD then the path is still wrong.